# ExpandoObject not being populated with all values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, expandoobject

I have inherited a project and cannot talk to/ do not know the original developer to ask this question to. This is a .NET MVC project.

This is the first time I have worked with ExpandoObject so I am trying to learn. I am following the style that was originally used where information was added to an xml file and then parsed and stored in the `Model`. When I debug the issue and inspect `Model` in the view, I only see one value of the two I have in the XML.

Here is the XML that I appened to the end of the file:

```
    <Home_Index>  <NewsletterSignup>
    <SignUpMessage>
      <Copy>
        <![CDATA[
          Want up to $20 in savings?    
        ]]>
      </Copy>
    </SignUpMessage>
    <SignUpMessage>
      <Copy>
        <![CDATA[
          Sign up, stay connected &amp; save up to $20.    
        ]]>
      </Copy>
    </SignUpMessage>
  </NewsletterSignup>
</Home_Index>
```

So when I inspect the `Model`, all I see is the second `<SignUpMessage>` but not the first.

Here is the code that creates the ExpandoObject:

```
public class XmlToDynamic
{
    public static dynamic Parse(String file, XElement node = null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file) && node == null) return null;

        node = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file) ? XDocument.Load(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(file)).Root : node;

        IDictionary<String, dynamic> result = new ExpandoObject();

        var pluralizationService = PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));

        node.Elements().ForEach(gn =>
        {
            var isCollection = gn.HasElements &&
                (
                    gn.Elements().Count() > 1 &&
                    gn.Elements().All(e => e.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == gn.Elements().First().Name.LocalName) ||
                        gn.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == pluralizationService.Pluralize(gn.Elements().First().Name.LocalName).ToLower()
                );

            var items = isCollection ? gn.Elements().ToList() : new List<XElement> { gn };

            var values = new List<dynamic>();

            items.ForEach(i => values.Add((i.HasElements) ? Parse(null, i) : i.Value.Trim()));

            result[gn.Name.LocalName] = isCollection ? values : values.FirstOrDefault();
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to choose the two `<SignUpMessage>` and randomly chose one to display.

Also worth noting is that the xml file has content that is correctly parsed before where I added `<NewsletterSignup>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a parent element to hold your two SignUpMessages:

```
<Home_Index>
  <NewsletterSignup>
    <SignUpMessages>
      <SignUpMessage>
        <Copy>
          `<![CDATA[`
          Want up to $20 in savings?    
          `]]>`
        </Copy>
      </SignUpMessage>
      <SignUpMessage>
        <Copy>
          `<![CDATA[`
          Sign up, stay connected &amp; save up to $20.    
          `]]>`
        </Copy>
      </SignUpMessage>
    </SignUpMessages>
  </Home_Index>
</NewsletterSignup>
```

The unclosed tags for Home_Index and NewsletterSignup are also cause for concern, so I've closed them off.

Comment: Thanks, but in my `xml` file they are closed. I'm not sure why, when I copied them to the post, they got cut off.

Comment: Ok, no worries.  The main thing is to add <SignUpMessages> parent element as I've done in the snippet above.  This will give you a collection of two <SignUpMessage> objects, which I hope is what you need.

Comment: in my edited xml, `<NewsletterSignup>` should act as the parent to `<SignUpMessage>`, right? Or is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: I see what you're getting at.  I've edited my answer so the hierarchy is better